# Gitlab mail notification on issue creation

Tags: git, gitlab

I am using https://gitlab.com/ and I would like that an email is sent when a new issue is created or an issue is modified (to the creator and to the assignee).

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Emails are already sent to the assignee, but not to the creator.

Why do you want to send an email to the creator, since he just... created the issue?

If the email is not being sent to the assignee, make sure to check the notification settings under `/profile/notifications`, or specify precisely when this happens so we can reproduce (what is the project access level? is the assignee a member? etc.)

Comment: When the issue is modified or closed I want the creator to be informed because indeed he is the creator :).

Comment: @Abbadon can you expand a bit on that? Why does he want a notification since he just created it, so he knows it? Maybe you have a valid rationale, but I think most people don't see it. Also in that case, make a feature request at: http://feedback.gitlab.com explaining that rationale clearly.